# Seeking list of project properties that can be written in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, xml, qgs

The methods `QgsProject.instance().writeEntry()` and `QgsProject.instance().readEntry()` can be used to programmatically set project properties. According to the QGIS API reference the properties correspond to those of the .qgs project file (or rather to the xml tags within it).
However, I'm interested in a compact list of all attributes that can be modified.

Is there any list which provides an overview of all properties that can be accessed using the above methods?

Comment: Tricky, because various bits of QGIS define their own properties for their section in the file. Hence the valid properties are defined all over the QGIS codebase.